# Coroutines running on the main thread instead of background

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines, kotlin-coroutines

I have an application in which user picks a pdf from file explorer and then I need to convert that pdf to base 64.

Following is my code to convert pdf to base64

```
private fun convertImageFileToBase64(imageFile: File?): String {
        return FileInputStream(imageFile).use { inputStream ->
            ByteArrayOutputStream().use { outputStream ->
                Base64OutputStream(outputStream, Base64.DEFAULT).use { base64FilterStream ->
                    inputStream.copyTo(base64FilterStream)
                    base64FilterStream.flush()
                    outputStream.toString()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

so in the `onActivityResult` where I am getting the pdf file I am writing the following code

```
launch {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        generatedBase64 = convertImageFileToBase64(file)
    }

    //upload generatedBase64 to server
}
```

But the code runs on the main thread instead of background thread and my ui freezes for some time if the pdf file is large. I also tried AsyncTask and tried performing the conversion in `doInBackground` method but I am facing the same issue

Comment: AsyncTask is mostly crap imo. A regular old Thread should work. Eg Thread t = new Thread (......

Comment: @CmosBattery But what's wrong with coroutines why my ui freezes when converting pdf to base64

Comment: what do you mean 'freezes'? you mean some ui codes like onclicklisteners don't run while this is running? or just the "//upload generatedbase64 to server" part?

Comment: what context do you use to launch the coroutine? I guess you use something like this: `Dispatchers.Main + Job()`. If so then in place where you have the comment "upload generatedBase64 to server" it will run on the main thread. You need to switch contexts like you did for invoking `convertImageFileToBase64` function.

Comment: @kamyarhaqqani onclicklisteners don't run

Comment: @Sergey yes I am using the Dispatchers.Main + Job()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use something like `Dispatchers.Main + Job()` as a context to launch the coroutine then in place where you have the comment "upload generatedBase64 to server" it will run on the main thread. You need to switch contexts like you did for invoking `convertImageFileToBase64` function to upload `generatedBase64` to the server, i.e use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`:

```
launch {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        generatedBase64 = convertImageFileToBase64(file)
        //upload generatedBase64 to server here
    }
    // do UI stuff here, e.g. show some message, set text to TextView etc.
}
```

Comment: will give a try and let you know